# Sum values of two same format files in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I got a txt format like below, each user(a,b,c...) has a numeric value

old values file

```
a,1000130103828
b,9230032882842
c,98247249242402
...
```

and new values file

```
a,20200203020
b,1029328428429
c,102492290011
...
```

How can I easily calc a new file by sum each user's value in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call awk?

```
 awk '-F,' '{users[$1]+=$2}; END{for (u in users) {printf("%s,%s\n", u, users[u])}}' file1 file2 > sumFile
```

output

```
cat sumFile
a,1020330306848
b,10259361311271
c,98349741532413
```

Its likely that with more than 3 users, the output will not be sorted as it is in your file, if you need sorting, add

```
  | sort -t, -k1
```

to the above.

IHTH.

Comment: yes, thanks I had corrected on my test, but didn't copy it to my answer. Answer should now work. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ join -j1 -t, old new | tr ',' ' ' | while read r; do
> ra=($r); echo ${ra[0]},$(( ${ra[1]} + ${ra[2]} )); done
a,1020330306848
b,10259361311271
c,98349741532413
```

where `old` and `new` are the two files you have. Redirect to a new file if needed by adding

```
> newfile
```